# google placepicker for ios and BackgroundMapViewController.swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm trying to implement google's placepicker for ios.
There is some demo code at:

https://github.com/googlemaps/maps-sdk-for-ios-samples/tree/master/GooglePlacePicker/GooglePlacePickerDemos

And i get most of it except the line in the file PickAPlaceViewController.swift

```
  var mapViewController: BackgroundMapViewController?
```

In the github repo Google have provided their own class BackgroundMapViewController.

Do I need to create an instance of this class to use the place picker?

Or can I just use a GMSMapView like I ordinarily would with google maps.

Thanks.

Comment: What you want here choose Place from Map ? if yes you just use already create GMSPlacePickerViewController in your project.

Comment: Hi CodeChanger. I didn't really understand what you're trying to say. Can you please clarify that. Thx.

Comment: Please check my answer for Place Picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Places Controller you just need below code to show or present Places Controller in your App.

Put this in ur Button Action method :

```
// Create a place picker. Attempt to display it as a popover if we are on a device which
    // supports popovers.
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)
    placePicker.delegate = self
    placePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    placePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = pickAPlaceButton
    placePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = pickAPlaceButton.bounds

    // Display the place picker. This will call the delegate methods defined below when the user
    // has made a selection.
    self.present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope This will helps to show Place Picker in your app.